# How to get subcategories on one page and products on another page?

Tags: magento2, products, sub-categories

I have category seating and I have some subcategories (sofa,chair) in it.
I want one category page that shows list of sub categories and another page which shows all the products of the seating.
We can add Id or some parameter to differentiate both the page.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want two different pages for the same category. But one of them has to have only links to the subcategories, while the other does contain all the products. There are multiple ways to achieve this. My suggestion would be to create two categories.

1. The actual category without the subcategories. Lets call this one Seating. This will be the default page as Magento usually builds it up.
2. A second category with the subcategories. Lets call this one Seating Overview.

You can open up the second category and under Display Setting -> Display Mode change the page to Static Block only and save. This will now leave the second category empty.

Create a CMS block containing the links to the subcategories. You can use the wysiwyg editor or prettify your category links with some images. Some basic html knowlegde wil help you along.

Go back to the second category and select the CMS block under Content -> Add CMS Block and save. Your block will be visible in the second category.

Both categories will appear in the menu, but will have different functions.

Note: you can also achieve the same result with the widget implementation. The luma theme's men/women categories are great examples of how to pretty up these general overview pages.